How do I identify why my HTML/CSS website is not scrolling?
I have a simple website I am working on, and it suddenly stopped scrolling when I test it out, even though it had been working for a long time. I was troubleshooting a different issue but never made any permanent changes to the code.
I have tried all the immediately available solutions on the internet(overflow:scroll, height:100%, removing fixed positions) but nothing has changed. please help... I do not have the knowledge or experience to identify the problem


@font-face {
  font-family: "power_red_and_blueregular";
  src: url("pkmnrs-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"), url("pkmnrs-webfont.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

html {
  background-image: url(/deco2.png);
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

body {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  border: black 10px inset;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: futura;
  background-image: url(/planktongreen.jpeg);
}

h2 {}

p {
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: black 10px inset;
  font-family: "power_red_and_blueregular";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #000, -3px 3px 2px #000, -3px -3px 2px #000, 3px -3px 2px #000;
  padding: 10px;
  background-image: url(/planktongreen.jpeg);
}

.music {
  background-color: navajowhite;
}

img {
  border: 0;
}

a:link {
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-family: futura;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  <!--background-image: url(planktongreen.jpeg);
  ->padding: 4px;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #000, -3px 3px 2px #000, -3px -3px 2px #000, 3px -3px 2px #000;
}

a:visited {
  color: whitesmoke;
}

a:hover {
  color: palegoldenrod;
}

#image {
  text-align: center;
  <!---background-image: url(tv.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -->
}

#box {
  background-image: url(/backgroundwebsite.png);
  text-align: center;
  border: black 10px inset;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  padding: 30px;
}

#box h1 {
  background-image: url(plankton2.jpeg);
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #000, -3px 3px 2px #000, -3px -3px 2px #000, 3px -3px 2px #000;
}

#box p {
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #000, -3px 3px 2px #000, -3px -3px 2px #000, 3px -3px 2px #000;
}

#box h2 {
  font-family: cursive;
  color: tomato;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #000, -3px 3px 2px #000, -3px -3px 2px #000, 3px -3px 2px #000;
}

#box2 {
  background-image: url(/space2.gif);
  text-align: center;
  border: black 10px inset;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  padding: 30px;
}

#box2 h1 {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-image: url(plankton2.jpeg);
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #000, -3px 3px 2px #000, -3px -3px 2px #000, 3px -3px 2px #000;
  width: max-content;
}

#links {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-image: url(planktongreen.jpeg);
  border: black 5px inset;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-right: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 4px;
}

audio {
  width: 480px;
  height: 20px;
}

.banner {
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
}

#astro {
  text-align: left;
}

#sun {
  text-align: right;
}

#family {
  text-align: center;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" width="100%" initial-scale=1.0>>
</head>
<style>
  #news {
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  #news img {
    border: black 15px outset;
  }
  
  #news h2 {
    text-align: center;
    color: palegoldenrod;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: futura;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #000, -3px 3px 2px #000, -3px -3px 2px #000, 3px -3px 2px #000;
    margin: 50px;
  }
</style>

<head title="Bill Diver's Passionproject"> </head>

<body>
  <div id="image">
    <a href="praise.html" target="_blank"><img src="/logopluspic.gif" width="670" /></a>
    <div class="music"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="links">
    <a href="music.html">Bill's Music</a
      >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a
        href="https://linktr.ee/billdiver"
        target="_blank"
        >Bill's Socials</a
      >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a
        href="mailto:billdiverinvestments@gmail.com"
        >Booking BDP</a
      >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="collage.html"
        >Motivational Posters!</a
      >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a
        href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYj4Q3R-ssA"
        target="_blank"
        >Videos</a
      >
    </div>
    <div id="box">
      <h1 style="color: gainsboro">
        CLICK HERE TO<br /><a
          href="http://billdiversguestbook.123guestbook.com/"
          target="_blank"
          ><img src="guestbook99.gif" width="400"
        /></a>
    </h1>
    <div id="wait">
      <h2 style="text-align: left">
        <br />Listen to our hit song
        <sup><img src="quote2.png" height="30" /></sup
          ><sub><img src="waitpink.png" width="115" /></sub>&nbsp;<sup
            ><img src="quote1.png" height="30"></sup>
      </h2>
      <p style="color: palegoldenrod">
        "Wait!" by Bill Diver's Passionproject, out on all platforms!
        <br /><br /><audio controls>
            <source src="Wait!%20MASTER.wav" autoplay="true" loop="true" />
          </audio>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/><br/>
  <div class="banner" style="text-align: center">
    <a href="realestate.html" target="_blank"><img src="forsale_ticker.gif" width="600" /></a>
  </div>
  <div id="family">
    <a href="family.html" target="_blank"><img src="havefamily.gif" width="300" /></a>
  </div>
  <div id="box2">
    <div id="sun">
      <a href="higher.html" target="_blank"><img src="sun.gif" width="75px" /></a>
    </div>
    <h1 style="color: gainsboro">BIO:</h1>
    <div id="astro">
      <a href="axis.html" target="_blank"><img src="astro.gif" width="75px" /></a>
    </div>
    <p style="color: palegoldenrod">
      Bill Diver's Passionproject is an ambitious indie/art rock endeavor seeking to latch on to the unplaced feelings of loss, loneliness, and disconnect created by the world's dependence on the internet for genuine experience. They accomplish this through
      tight melodies, dense vocal movements. powerful walls of sound, unique production; and as a part of the larger "Bill Diver" experiment.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="news">
    <h2>Headlines!</h2>
    <h3>Click image to read the full article</h3>
    <a href="https://www.westword.com/music/bill-divers-passionproject-releases-debut-ep-16485925" target="_blank"><img src="westwordscreenshot.jpeg" width="200px" /></a>
  </div>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="banner">
    <a href="theboard.html" target="_blank"><img src="business.htm_cmp_zero110_bnr.gif" width="600" /></a>
  </div>
  <br /><br /><br />
</body>

</html>




<head title... is incorrect, do you mean header, or the title tag of head which is empty? Setting heights on html and body are suspect, try min height. Run your code through a validator to see if there's any errors.

Also, avoid the use of &nbsp; for styling purpose. Use CSS instead. Also use /**/ for CSS comments, not <!-- -->

Running your HTML through https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input highlights a lot of errors. Best to cure those first.
